# Long image pasted into upload pushes footer up:

Tags: bug, design, footer, uploader

If you use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to upload the image, and it is a very, very long one, the footer is pushed down:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

This should possibly be adjusted so that it moved the submit box up.

Comment: Well then collapse it, so you can't see all the image, or make it smaller, or squish it...? Why are you going through bugs on MSE if you don't care at all about bugs?

Comment: Bug?  I don't see a bug.

Comment: I do, it's pushing down the footer when that's meant to be the footer. I'd rather you didn't come along posting comments like that...

Comment: I'd rather not see [tag:feature-request]s tagged as [tag:bug], however I'm not going to imply you should go away.  That would be rude.  Nyah.

Comment: Not sure how wanting to see the Footer stay as the Footer is a feature-request, but your choice.

Comment: @Tim If you think of it instead as a separate object laid on top of the page, then it makes sense for the page's footer to stay where it is while the long object you're putting on top of it is naturally longer. The darkened page even indicates that this metaphor is the one intended. With that metaphor model, it's not a bug but actually operating correctly.

Comment: This a real [tag:bug] and a real problem that must be fixed, why are we arguing??

Comment: Is it a bug, or have you just made "on-top" content push *past* the footer? Why would the submit ("confirm" actually) button need to be pushed up? Also, can't you just move that box around as needed? I'm not saying you are wrong about anything, I'm just saying I don't really see any issue.

Comment: @James I'm saying that by default, it pushes down below the footer...

Comment: So what else *should* happen? In this case you could argue to move the pop-up further up, but what if the pop-up was taller than your screen height (screen sizes/resolutions etc)? Or the pop-up was taller than the entire page content (as it almost is in your example - do you add some padding somewhere?

Comment: @James if the popup is taller, it should push the footer down. I'm not offering a solution here, just saying that there is a bug. The footer is the footer and should stay the footer.

Comment: I'm not really suggesting you should propose a solution, but your stating there is a bug means *something else* has to happen. And I don't think anything else is better than the current outcome. "*The footer is the footer and should stay as the footer*" + should stay attached under the last content above the footer, and a separate pop-up should not change that. Otherwise, you're suggesting if there's a popup there should be a potentially huge white space (padding) above the footer. Which would look like a *real* bug if a popup suddenly pushed the footer down. It would feel *awkward* imo

Comment: @James but there is whitespace there anyway...

Comment: I don't really know what you mean. I think perhaps we have different definitions of "footer". Have a look at my answer, let me know if I've hit the nail on the head anywhere, and I'll adjust it as needed :)

Answer (score 1):

> If you use Ctrl+V to upload the image, and it is a very, very long
>   one, the footer is pushed down:

The definition of a "footer" is open to interpretation, however I *presume* you mean "the blue bit at the bottom of all pages with links in it" as this is the most common use of the word.

Based on your image, the footer is not "pushed down" it remains in place directly under the content above it, exactly where it would be without the pop-up box.
The pop-up box is simply additional content on top of the footer and which spreads *beyond* the footer.

As such, perhaps by "footer" you actually mean the bottom of the page, *after* the blue box with links in it?

Either way, I don't see an issue with the pop up stretching beyond the footer (blue box with links in) as per your image.

> This should possibly be adjusted so that it moved the submit box up.

But the top of the box should also be around the top of the *edit area*, as it currently is, because that's what it is relevant to.
And if it's a large box then it simply extends down as required, as it does now as per your image.

I see no actual problem/bug with this design, the box has to go somewhere.

*In comments you stated:*

> if the popup is taller, it should push the footer down

I'm not really sure what you mean by this. Isn't this what you are reporting is the actual bug - it moves the footer and it should be the box which moves?

There is content behind the popup, what *exactly* do you feel should be pushed down, or pushed up, or *is* pushed down?

### Some images

(Please excuse poor images, am on Windows ATM and only have MS Paint)

### 1) Footer pushed down

[image: box pushes footer down]

### 2) box moved up footer moved down

Or, popup moved up to the question title (as far as I want to go otherwise it will be encroaching on the nav bar) and footer down:

[image: box moved up footer pushed down]

### 3) box up footer not moved

Alternatively, in case I've misunderstood your definition of "footer", not pushing the "footer" down as per the above two images, but moving the box up and allowing it to sit over the footer.

The problem with this is I've manually edited an image, and getting this to work from code would be fiddly, especially for what change it makes.

Your best bet would perhaps to suggest "the box appears at the top of the *question title*", although this again is not ideal as it's more relevant to the edit area.

Here's the best I could get - **is this what you meant**?:

[image: footer not moved, box up]

---

### Improved?

Well, arguably, but given this needs to be *coded* I still think that the current way as per your image in your question is the best way to handle this.
That also accounts for screen sizes etc, and any other scenarios, as it *gracefully* uses any height down over as it requires.

### Bug?

A bug is when something is not by design, or an element is by design but causes issues with something else (etc). And I really don't see a "bug" here as this is likely by design and causes no issues (none that I can see or you have stated).

Perhaps you'd be better off posting a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) asking for the changes.

Comment: Those white space sections should be the grey of the background. But what I mean is the first one.

Comment: Ah, I'd re-edit if I wasn't on Windows. But even with grey background, I don't like "1". Don't like the huge space between content and footer, rather than just an on-top temporary box push down the very bottom. Each to their own though :)